# Box-Shadow Won't work on my website

Tags: html, css, image, shadow

When trying to display image effects on my website they don't display.
If I run the image on jsfiddle.net it works perfectly fine. However my image doesn't work when i test it inside all my code. I want a border shadow effect all around the image. The code to do so is in my code but as you can see in my web site image there is no shadow.

Here is the image when I test it in jsfiddle.net without an image.
[image]

My code:

CSS:

```
#collage-container {

        /*width: 699px;*/
        width: 800px;
        /*height: 510px;*/
        height: 320px;
        float: left;
        margin-left: 200px;
        margin-top: 10px;
        background-color: #DADADA;
    }

    #collage-one{

    width: 699px;
    height: 300px;
    margin-left: 50px;
    margin-top: 10px;
    box-shadow: 0 0 20px black;
    }
```

HTML:

```
<div id = "collage-container">
    <img src = "longblue.jpg" id = "collage-one"/>
    </div>
```

[image]

Update: here is all my css

```
       <head>

   <style type = "text/css">


    /* Formating for body of Web Site */
    * {margin: 0; padding: 0;}
    body {
     font-family: times new roman;
     background-color: #ebebeb;


     }

    /* Fixed screen size so objects don't shift */
     #screen {
     /*
     min-width: 768px;
     min-height: 100% !important;
     margin-bottom: 30px;
     */
     /* This locks everything in place*/
     top:0px;
     margin: 0 auto; 
     width:1500px;
     height: 100%;
         padding-top:0;
         padding-bottom: 30px;
         margin-bottom: 150px;
         postion: absolute;
     margin-left: 70px;

     }

    /* Format for black strip header  */
     #header {
        background-color: black;
        height: 168px;
        width: 100%;
        position: relative;
     }

    /* Class1: Holds the navigation buttons in header   */
    .container {
        width: 960px;
        height: auto;
        margin: 0 auto;
        margin-left: 0;
    }

    /* Class2: Holds the small containers for short articles   */
    .containerShort {
                width: 480px;
                height: auto;
                margin: 0 auto;
    }

    /* Sub Classes: For Class2  */
    .short1 {

        right: 30px;
    }

    .short2 {
        right: 30px;

    }

    /* Format for Tree logo in header   */
    #logoArea {
        width: 300px;
        height: 168px;
        background-image: url(treesmall.jpg);
        float: left;
        margin-left: 30px;
        }

    /* Formating for location of navagation buttons  */
    #navArea
    {
        height: 100%;
        float: right;
        margin-right: 0px;
        margin-top: 80px;
        margin-left: 100px;


    }

    /* Removes the bullets for navagation buttons in header  */
    #nav
    {
        list-style: none;

    }

    /* Navagation formating */
    #nav a
    {
        color: white;
        text-decoration: none; /*removes underline*/

    }

    /* Formats the links of navagation buttons   */
    #nav li
    {
        float: left;
        margin-left: 60px;
        background-color: #252525;
        padding: 8px;
        bording: 1px solid silver;
        border-radius: 5px;

    }

    /* Makes a hovering effect where when the mouse hovers over the 
     links they change color  */
    #nav li:hover
    {
        background-color: gray;
    }

    /* Sub class formating for container class  */
    .page
    {
        background-color: white;
        padding: 10px;
        margin-top: 10px;
        width: 1100px;
        float: right;
        border-radius: 5px;
        padding-bottom: 1px;

    }

    /* Side quote article main page */
    .article
            {
                background-color: #ebebeb;
                padding-top: 1px;
                margin-top: 20px;
                width: 120px;
                float: right;
                border-radius: 20px;
                height: 300px;
                border: 1px solid black;
                margin-right: 20px;
                text-align: left;

    }

    /* Formating for left sidebar of information  */
    #sidebar {

    background-color: #B4B4B4;
    height: auto;
    width:350px;
    float:left;
    margin-top: 10px;
    border-radius: 5px;
    padding: 10px;
    color: #483D8B;
    }

    /* footer formating  */
    #footer {

        background-color: black;
        height: 40px;
        width: 1500px;
        color: white;
        padding-top: 10px;
        position: relative center;
        bottom: 0;
        text-align: center;
        margin-left:70px;
    }
    /* Formating of Header quote   */
    #quote {
        color: white;
        float: right;
    }

    /* Paragraph formating  */
    p {
        color: black;
        margin-bottom: 20px;
        padding: 5px;
        padding-left: 40px;
    }

    p.light {

    color: white !important;
    margin-bottom: 60px;
    padding: 5px;
    padding-left: 40px;

    }

    p .imagespace {

    padding-left: 40px;
    margin: auto;
    }

    h3 {
        margin-bottom: 60px;
    }

    h2 {

    font-family: "Times New Roman";
    font-style: oblique;
    }

    #collage-container {

        /*width: 699px;*/
        width: 800px;
        /*height: 510px;*/
        height: 320px;
        float: left;
        margin-left: 200px;
        margin-top: 10px;
        background-color: #DADADA;
    }

    #collage-one{

    width: 699px;
    height: 300px;
    margin-left: 50px;
    margin-top: 10px;
    box-shadow: 0 0 20px black;
    }

    /*#collage-two,#collage-three,
    #collage-four{

    width: 226px;
    height: 200px;
    padding: 5px;
    background-color: black;
    background-position: top center;
    float: right;

    }*/

    /*#space {

    width:300px;
    height: 508px;
    background-color: white;
    float: left;
    margin-top: 0;
    margin-left: 120px;
     box-shadow: hshadow, vshadow blur color 
    box-shadow: 10px 0 20px #B4B4B4;
    border-radius: 10px;
    }*/

    #ego {
    box-shadow: 0 0 20px #B4B4B4;
    }

    #marquee{

    color: #483D8B;
    margin-top: 10px;
    margin-bottom: 0px;
    width: 1025px;
    float: right;

    }





   </style>

   </head>
```

Comment: Works fine on JSFiddle with Chrome as you mentioned.

Comment: Ya I seem to always experience issues like this where it works when i test but not when implemented in my page.

Comment: We would need to see the CSS for your site as there could easily be something overriding your style.

Comment: Have you tried putting the box-shadow on your collage container as apposed to collage-one?

Comment: @hungerstar I added the rest of my css

Comment: @KyleT I just tried to add it to the container and nothing showed either

Comment: After your `#collage-one` selector you have the following selector ,`#space`, partially commented out creating improper syntax.

Comment: @AlyssaCooke What are you testing this on? localhost or via host? It could simply be a caching issue. Try holding down ctrl and F5 to force a reload of your site. This should clear out any lingering properties held in your browser cache and load everything to date.

Comment: @hungerstar ya i saw that and fixed it. Still didn't correct anything

Comment: Do you have any other stylesheets being included into your site via a plugin or something like that?

Comment: @KyleT i forced shutdown but it didn't change anything

Comment: What browser are you viewing this on?  You need to use several CSS properties for all browser support: http://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/b/box-shadow/

Comment: @hungerstar I only have one css which is the one posted. I don't see what the issue is with my shadowing on my image... mind blown XD

Comment: @Phillips126 as long as the OP is not using IE8 or less they are good to go.

Comment: @Phillips126 oh google chrome works with it but not my IE?? weird since jsfiddle was IE

Comment: Some "fiddle" sites include the extra properties such as -webkit to save developer time.  I'm not sure if jsfiddle does that, just thought I would ask!  IE is the worst.... :(

Answer (score 0):

From advice in comments, looks like I have to fix my shadow to accept more browser versions.

Thanks everyone I will play with it.

Main help: @Phillips126

Comment: What version of IE are you using if you don't mind me asking?  As @hungerstar mentions, later versions of IE include more CSS support.

Comment: I can't figure out which one I have. And trying to get your examples to work... they are not accepting them LOL

Comment: @Phillips126 Oh its version: 10.0.9200.17148